# Is there a way to fix unicode error while printing the current dir path?

Tags: python, import, operating-system, file-handling

I am using python 3.8.1 in win 10 64bit OS.
write .py files in IDLE editor.
I try to run this code by writing it in a .py file:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

the exact same code returns the path in interpreter . but not when I try to run the file.
It shows:
syntax error:
[image: Unicode error ... can't decode byte in position 35-36.\Uxxx....]

Comment: Does then code run when executed in Python directly (without IDLE)?

Comment: You mean in the cmd?